# Delphi FMX function to open a local file fails on Android platform

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I require a cross-platform function to open a file using any app on the device registered to be able to open the file type concerned, along the lines of the WinAPI function `ShellExecute` in Windows. Using various code examples that I found on Stack-overflow I finally came up with the following code which compiles with Delphi 10.3.

```
uses
 {$ifdef Android}
  FMX.Helpers.Android, AndroidAPI.Helpers,
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  AndroidApi.JNI.Net, AndroidApi.JNI.JavaTypes;
  {$endif Android}
  {$ifDef MSWindows}
  Winapi.ShellAPI, Winapi.Windows;
  {$endif MSWindows} 

procedure OpenFile(FilePathname: string; DisplayError: Boolean);
const
  COption= 0;
var
  Extension: string;
  {$ifdef Android}
  Intent: JIntent;
  URI: Jnet_Uri;
  {$endif Android}
  Result: integer;
begin
  Extension:= LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(FilePathname));
  {$ifdef Android}
  URI := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('file:///' + FilePathname));
  Intent:= TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  case COption of
    0: Intent.setData(URI);  
    1:
      if Extension= '.pdf' then
        Intent.setDataAndType(URI,StringToJString('application/pdf'))
      else if Extension= '.txt' then
        Intent.setDataAndType(URI,StringToJString('text/*'));
  end;
  try
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      begin
        if DisplayError then
          ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message);
      end;
  end;
  {$endif Android}
  {$ifdef MSWindows}
  Result:= ShellExecute(0, 'Open', PChar(FilePathname), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  {$endif MSWindows}
end;
```

Applying this function to a local .PDF file on an SD card on an Android 9 device, the following exception is thrown:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:////SDCard/test.pdf exposed
>   beyond app through Intent.getData()

I have found on StackOverflow the following thread which addresses this problem:

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

However the idea of having to declare and use a class inheriting from the Java class File-provider in order to give access to a particular file or folder and make it accessible to other apps, and then document this in the **AndroidManifest.xml** seems greatly over-complicated, particularly considering that all the files in the SD card are public by definition.

My questions, therefore, are:

- Is there a simpler way of dealing with this issue in Delphi FMX
  10.3+?
- If not, how does one go about creating a Object Pascal class in Delphi inheriting from a Java class? A code example would be appreciated.

**Addendum:**

From a link to this post I have found the following code by Dave Nottage:

```
procedure OpenPDFA(const AFileName: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LAuthority: JString;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
  LUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(AFileName)));
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  LIntent.setDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('application/pdf'));
  LIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

However the class `TJFileProvider` is flagged up in the Delphi compiler as an undeclared identifier. The `uses` list in my code seems to be the same as in Dave Nottage's code. So where is TJFileProvider declared?

Comment: You do not have to declare a class inheriting from FileProvider. You can use FileProvider directly. In the code it is only adding one line. In the manifest file declare the provider. Well.. in Java.

Comment: `TJFileProvider` is located in `Androidapi.JNI.Support`

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated my project from Delphi 10.4 to Delphi 11.1 and TJFileProvider is flagged up as an undeclared identifier as well.

TJcontent_FileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(....)

instead of

TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(....)

I hope this helps